# Error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: boost, daemon

When starting the daemon, it says this: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to solve it?  Everything is set...

When starting the daemon, it says this: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to solve it?  Everything is set..